# C# Find Duplicate Values in a Datatable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am receiving an Excel spreadsheet that is being converted into a DataTable. The resulting table will have values something like this:

```
    Person | Billing Street | Billing City | Home Street | Home City
    ------ | ---------------|--------------|-------------|-----------
    Bob    | 100 B Street   | BCity        | 123 My St   | HCity
    Bob    | 101 A Street   | BCity        | 101 My Ave  | HCity
    Bob    | 100 B Street   | BCity        | PO Box 42   | HCity
```

I need to take this data and get the 5 unique address to be inserted into the db. There will thousands of "people" in the table and some will have multiple addresses like Bob and some will have just one of each.

Any thoughts/help would be appreciated.
Thanks

**EDIT:**
I apologize for not adding expected results to the question it was an oversight on my part late in the day. The expected results are as follows:

```
    Person | Address        | City
    -------|----------------|---------
    Bob    | 100 B Street   | BCity
    Bob    | 101 A Street   | BCity
    Bob    | 123 My St      | HCity
    Bob    | 101 My Ave     | HCity
    Bob    | PO Box 42      | HCity
```

To the comments that I need to write code and show my work: Sorry but corporate policy prohibits the posting of code directly to outside sources. I could have written pseudo code but I feel sure that would not have sufficed either.

To anyone that happens upon this question the answer I came up with was to iterate over the final DataTable and create a string[] of the DataColumnNames, then do a DefaultView.ToTable(true, string[]) to get the distinct values.

Thanks

Comment: `Any thoughts/help would be appreciated` I would write a code and try something, and then would ask what I am doing wrong

Comment: What exact part of this question you have troubles with? Reading the excel file, finding unique adresses or storing the data into the db?

Comment: this is actually very simple to do when working with a DataTable where you can use a Filter / Select once you get the data into a datatable.. but sure would be nice to see existing code that you have... What have you actually tied thus far...?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a UNION

```
SELECT [Person] as [Perdson],[Billing Street] as [Street], [Billing City] as [City] FROM Tbl
UNION
SELECT [Person],[Home Street] [Home City] from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to get distinct addresses from Address Column

```
dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, new String[] { "columnName" });
```